# How do I get historical AccountInfos at timestamp x, y, and z?

Tags: account

I would like to create transaction graphs for research purposes. To do this I need to obtain the data in the account at specific timestamps. What's the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Historical accountInfo is not available by default.

A way you can get account state in the past is taking transactions executed on that state and replaying backwards. You can also start storing all account state at different points with [geyser plugins](https://docs.solana.com/developing/plugins/geyser-plugins) and query from there.

Comment: Hopefully someone will build a service around this proposed solution!