# Is it possible to get past versions of an account?

Tags: account, rpc, history

Is there anyway to get the past versions of a Solana account?

Comment: Hey, do you mean to get historical data? At a given time, what stage the account was in?

Comment: This might help: https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/97/50

Comment: Not yet, not. You could run a Geyser plugin to get this data. But you might want to reach out to Richard Patel. He's working on a diff compression algorithm to save historical account data: https://twitter.com/terorie_dev/status/1549633797922213888?s=20&t=hGUK9KaO2Smy5sA86RzPUg